# jQuery- Check if object value exists

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble checking if an object value already is set.

I have:

```
regObj = {};

function setvalue() {

  regObj.name = 'Bob';

}

function lateron() {
  if (!regObj.name) { // only do this if regObj.name has not been set already

    // perform some stuff 

  }
}
```

When `lateron` function is run, Im getting an error "can't find variable regObj".

What is the proper way to check if it exists already that will not throw an error?

Comment: `if (!regObj.name)` is perfectly fine whether the `.name` property exists or not.  It will not cause an error if the `name` property does not exist.  The problem here is that `regObj` is not available in whatever scope you are in.  My guess is that you declared `regObj` in some other function and it is not available outside that function.  You will have to fix how you declare `regObj` or pass it to the functions that need it.

Comment: You've accepted an answer that does not solve the error you have asked about.  So, if the code in the accepted answer works, then your code works too.  So, apparently you are confused about what you are asking or have not presented a clear question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to use `Object.hasOwnProperty()` function to identify that,

```
function lateron() {
  if (!regObj.hasOwnProperty("name")) {
    // perform some stuff 
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's issue.  If `regObj` isn't available in the scope of `lateron()`, this won't work either.  All this does is avoid inherited properties which has nothing to do with this particular issue.

Comment: This actually did fix the issue. It works great. The `regObj` is declared at the very top of the js page. With this answer, it corrected the issue perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: But if you look at the question, there's no reason this should work and the OP's code not, and then theres *`Im getting an error "can't find variable regObj"`*, which isn't really related at all ?

Comment: Your solution doesn't solve the problem in any way.  If your solution works, then the OP's code would work also.  This doesn't fix anything.  I have no idea why the OP accepted this answer because it doesn't change the original problem other than avoiding inherited properties which isn't what the question was about.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
function lateron() {
  //check regObj is defined or not and if defined then checked name is defined or not and if defined then checked its empty or not
  if (typeof(regObj)!="undefined" && typeof(regObj.name )!="undefined"  && regObj.name.trim()!="") {
    // perform some stuff 
  }
}
```

thanks